# Opengl supported version?

Tags: ubuntu

I've heard that it is possible to make a high performance computer with a rasberry pi cluster. I am thinking about doing this, but before I do it, I want to know what OpenGL version rasberry pi supports. (If it matters, the OS that I plan to install is ubuntu linux)

Comment: *"I've heard that it is possible to make a high performance computer with a rasberry pi cluster."* -> Probably false in terms of cost-efficiency (meaning, you could easily get a more "high performance computer" for less bucks than what it will cost you), but feel free to experiment and learn.

Answer (score 7):

The GPU supports GLES2.0 plus a couple of additional features.  With the open driver (enable it with raspi-config), you get GLES 2.0, and GL 2.1 with a few rarely-used features missing.

Comment: As a caveat for those to whom it might matter, I believe this means the GL 2.1 support is a pure software implementation, i.e., does not use GPU hardware acceleration (but please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: No, that would be wrong. It's a hardware implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is OpenGL 2.1. [See here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/another-update-raspbian/).